# How react-native storages work? Base principes

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Have a simple I guess, question.
How react-native storage works?

Does it works like a LocalStorage on Browser?

For example. I wanna make a simple todo app.
So I will save users todo in AsyncStorage.

So all I want to know

- can user just delete my data somehow?
- storage creates once to forever? On it creates every time with app starting?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncStorage works a lot like the LocalStorage on the browser, yes.

Storage is persistent across application restarts.

Comment: thx for responce!
So. In what cases my data can be removed? (exept "by myself" case)

Comment: I've tried to look it up but can't find the documentation on that. I'll update answer once I do.

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) works great.

Another more verbose option is [Realm](https://realm.io/)

> "Realm is a replacement for SQLite & Core Data"

Realm is used by many big names and recently added support for React Native.